# Xcode 8.3 does not ask for an user input

Tags: c++, xcode, input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH9fR.jpg)

I just install Xcode 8.3 from App Store and try to run those codes (from the photo) in C++ but it doesn't ask me to input a value to test the codes out. Please help me out?

Comment: You code looks correct, maybe you created the project wrong, have you tried making a new project?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please add the code to your question - [to format code in your question, see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). That makes it easier to help you!

Comment: @mistervunguyen I've run into the same problem.  Your program is actually waiting for input, once you type in an integer and press return the program will display your prompt.  Your program will work fine in previous versions of Xcode, but not Xcode 8.3.

Comment: @bhazero025 I created many new projects but they all came out the same result. Should I use another code editor? What a code editor should I use? I just start learning coding

Comment: @Steve That is weird huh. Any suggestion of another code editor for a beginner like me?

Comment: @mistervunguyen have you tried code blocks? or Eclipse with C++ ?

Comment: @bhazero025 I never tried any of them. I just tried Atom but it seems confusing to me

Comment: @mistervunguyen I've filed a tech assist report with Apple this morning and am waiting to hear back from them.  If you are registered as a developer with Apple, you can go to developer.apple.com/downloads and download Xcode 8.2.1.  Your code should work in that version.

Comment: @mistervunguyen Thought you might like to know that the release notes for Xcode 8.3.2 specifically list the fix for this issue in the list of improvements with this release of Xcode.

Comment: @Steve You are so helpful, I really appreciate that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. It looks like you need to add a new line character for it to appear in the console. That is

> std::cout << "Enter amount: $";

would not print, while

> std::cout << "Enter amount: $\n";

will